# Push segue from a view controller controlled by UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uitabbar, segue

Let's assume that a first view controller is connected with a UITabBarController and I want to make a push segue to the second view controller from this first view controller.

From my googling, it seems that a modal segue from a view controller connected with a UITabBarController hides the bottom tab bar, while a push segue doesn't. 
However, my push segue is also hiding my tab bar in the second view controller. I have overridden prepareForSegue method in the first view controller.

Below are images of my storybard and the simulator. Anyone has an idea why this is the case? Thank you in advance for your helps.
[image: The bottom right view controller seems to have bottom tab bar in the storyboard but the simulator doesn't show it TT]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your trouble is because your tabViewController is embedded in the navigation stack that you initialise with your login screen.

you need to rearrange things so that each of your tab bar controller tabs opens to a new navigation stack.

What I suggest

- your loginscreen should navigate to your tab bar controller with a modal/presenting segue, not a push segue. Remove the navController that encloses the loginscreen, you don't need it (well, even if you keep it, don't use a push segue, use a modal segue, and you won't then be referring back to that navController's viewController stack from inside your tab bar).
- embed each of the first viewControllers in your tabViewCOntroller inside a separate navController.

Now you can push segue within your tabViewController's tabs.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I was looking for this solution for hours and this fixed all my problems! Now I understand a little bit more about how UINavigationController works. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me too. I just ran into this problem, searched and 5 mins later, with this post, was able to resolve.

Comment: This answer saved me a ton of headache today