# Navigation bar from tab bar controller hides child's nav bar

Tags: ios, ios6

I am confused with behavior, I have Tab Bar Controller ( I enter on this controller from simple view controller which is embedded in navigation controller). I am confused why is that navigation bar from tab is covered up child navigation bar.[image]

When I start app and I enter at Browse Controller I cannot see Browse title, neither nav bar items which I added programmatically. Can somebody give me clue what is wrong ( I am new to this, I connect with push segue from tab to browse).

Comment: Have you added a navigation bar to the tab bar controller? If so, you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be the same as the one I addressed here:
[Push segue from a view controller controlled by UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694208/push-segue-from-a-view-controller-controlled-by-uitabbarcontroller/14695231#14695231)

What's happening is that your first NavigationController is creating a Navigation stack. Then you push-segue a TabViewController. That is added to the Nav stack, along with each of it's contained view controllers. However, when you PUSH SEGUE from one of those view controllers to some other view controller, the original navigation controller's stack is the one you are pushing on to. This is not contained inside the tab view controller, so the pushed view controller has no relationship with that tab view controller, just the original navigation controller stack. Therefore the tabs are not present.

The answer is to embed each of the tab controller's view controllers in a new navigation controller, and push on from those. The original navigation controller is just messing things up here...